# Missing keypress events when pasting into input while executing ajax in between

Tags: javascript, performance, keypress

I want to show a static html element which, if the user starts to type, changes into an input field and has the typed text prefilled. In basics, I can get this to work with such code (assuming the visible class toggles visibility):

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    if ($('input').hasClass('visible')) {
        return;
    }

    $('input').addClass('visible');
    $('input').val(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    $('input').focus();
    $('input')[0].setSelectionRange(1, 1);
});
```

However, in the real world code (see http://jsfiddle.net/gq3m7145/ for a testcase), the prefill is only filled until after an ajax call has been executed (it's done in its success callback). Then, typing several characters quickly after each other, only sets the first character and discards the rest. Probably, as the ajax call sits in between, the second character is never taken along to the input.

The quick & dirty solution is to not organize my code on this part: just fill the input directly when receiving it.

Is there a better way? For example collecting the received input until the ajax has finished and I'm ready to receive keypresses in the real input field?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "organize my code"?

Comment: I made separate functions for 1) showing the input (as more needs to happen than just showing it), 2) prefilling the input, and 3) focusing on the end of the input.

Comment: Well if that's the code that has problems, it'd be a good idea to post it here.

Comment: There is no bug in that code. If I type slower everything works fine. But I could try to make a working test case?

Comment: Thanks for the push @Pointy, I've created a test case which shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is being constantly bound to the key press. I have restructured your code and it performs well if you unbind the key press.

```
(function(){
    $(document).keypress(Keypress);

    function Keypress(event){
    ShowTextbox();
    PrefillInput();
    FocusOnEnd();
    $(document).off('keypress',Keypress)
}

function ShowTextbox(){
    $('input').addClass('visible');
}

function PrefillInput(){
    $('input').val(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    $('input').focus();
}

function FocusOnEnd(){
    $('input')[0].setSelectionRange(1, 1);
}})()
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qfzaLmyw/1/